# How to update the version of TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, typescript, web, razor

How to update the version of TypeScript for visual studio 2015 ASP.net MV5 project?

I searched using the Nuget but did not find it.
I have a problem in the razor intellisense (index.d.ts file) and need to updated to check if this will help.

Comment: `npm update ts` ?

Comment: is this the correct command? Nothing happens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To update TypeScript globally, run:

```
npm install -g typescript
```

Or just within a project:

```
npm install -save--dev typescript
```